# Equation numbers not showing up while using align together with mathtools

Tags: math-mode, numbering, align

In the following

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath]{mathtools}
  \mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs,showmanualtags,mathic,centercolon}

\renewcommand{\u}{\textbf{u}}
\renewcommand{\v}{\textbf{v}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \langle \u,\v \rangle_{\text {euc}} := \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i \quad \forall \u,\v \in \R^n
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I cannot get the numbering of the equation to work, but the formula still shows up as normal. Is there a problem with the code?

Comment: The code should be alright, though it's not clear to me why you are using `align` instead of `equation`. Can you please show a complete example? When I tried this (adding the `amsmath` and `amssymb` package and something like `\def\u{\mathfrak{u}} \def\v{\mathfrak{v}} \def\R{\mathbb{R}}` for testing purposes; just a guess...) it compiled perfectly *with* an equation number.

Comment: Please advise how the macros `\u` and `\v` are (re)defined in your document. (These two macros are usually already defined, to produce text-mode accents. Presumably, though, that's now how they're used in your document.) Also, how is `\R` defined?

Comment: And please do not use `_{\text{euc}}`, that construction will become italic, if the surrounding text is italic. Better to define `\newcommand\tsub[1]{_{\textup{#1}}}` (or `\textnormal`) and then use `\rangle\tsub{euc}`. It is also less typing.

Comment: dont use packages you dont understand. You use the "showonlyrefs" option. Which does exactly that, it only shows the number if the equation is referenced within the document, which it isnt, whence the lack of a number Edit: a begin document would probably also be nice

Comment: Given this mwe, the below solution of Zarko isn't an answer to your real question...

Comment: well the issue is I am new to this and have picked up a latex environment from a friend who wrote his thesis (which conformed to the school's requirements) so I wasn't sure what all the packages were apart from the common ones, i see the mistake now

Comment: Never redefine commands such as `\u` or `\v`: you'll regret it when you'll be adding bibliography items with Czech or Romanian authors.

Comment: @egreg thanks, ill rename the vectors something else then

Comment: @dimebucker91 -- A last advice for now: *don't* use templates or friends manuscripts out of the box. Just create a new `.tex` and add `\documentclass{<classname>} \begin{document} \end{document}` and build it from scratch. Every document needs its own treatment and most likely you don't need all your packages you use every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'showonlyrefs' option of `mathtools` makes the equation labels disappear. Cancel it out and you have the equation number back, as you requested:

[image: sol-pic]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath]{mathtools}
  \mathtoolsset{showmanualtags,mathic,centercolon}

\newcommand{\uvec}{\mathbf{u}}
\newcommand{\vvec}{\mathbf{v}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \langle \uvec,\vvec \rangle_{\textup{euc}} := \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i \quad \forall \uvec,\vvec \in \R^n
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

<sub>Note that I (1) did not redefine `\u` and `\v` (renamed them to `\uvec` and `\vvec`), (2) I used `\mathbf` instead of `\textbf` in the definitions of `\uvec` and `\vvec` and (3) `\textup` instead of `\text`.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Your code is ok. With a small modification (as suggested in comments of Ruben and Mico) and with assumption, that in your preamble is nothing what prevent shoving the equation number, the result is:

[image: result]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=1mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\renewcommand\u{\mathbf{u}}
\renewcommand\v{\mathbf{v}}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \langle \u,\v \rangle_{\textup{euc}} := 
    \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i \quad \forall\ \u,\v \in \R^n
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The same result you obtain with `align` as well with `gather` math environment. I didn't change the names of vectors because they are not influence on equation numbering, however it is not good to use such short names. For example `\u` is already somewhere defined, so I use for it `\renewcommand`. Better names are (as suggested in comments) are `\uvec`, `\vvec`. Similarly, it is good consider @daleif comment.